# How to wire L293D chip to a nodeMCU?

Tags: nodemcu, l293d

How do I wire an L293D motor controller chip to a nodeMCU?
I have tried to follow the instructions from this tutorial: [lastminuteengineers.com](https://lastminuteengineers.com/l293d-dc-motor-arduino-tutorial/)

One problem. I don't have a 5v pin?
Are there any alternative ways to wire this?

All of the other tutorials i see, only say to use a special other motor driver board with an L293D embedded in it, and with extras connected to the board.

Comment: why would you need a 5 V pin? ... you can't power the L293D from the nodeMCU anyway

Comment: Yeah. can you wire Vcc1 and Gnd (pin 5) [(L293D Breakout)](https://lastminuteengineers.com/wp-content/uploads/arduino/L293D-Dual-H-Bridge-Motor-Driver-IC-Pinout.png) on the L293D to an external source, and not the NodeMCU?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I am putting a logic level converter On the 3v pin to step it up to 5v